# How to change name of "~" directory? Debian 8

Tags: debian, directory, rename, home

I was providing an install directory for SteamCMD to install a server to, but it created a "~" directory as the parent directory for the directory I wanted.

Example: /home/steam/SteamCMD/~/ArkSurvivalServer/

I can't get into the server directory.

Any help?

Comment: It probably doesn't understand `~`.  Either reinstall, or quote the tilde when typing it, e.g. `cd '~'`.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can change the name:

```
cd /home/steam/SteamCMD/

mv \~ new_name
```